# Working with subtitles in sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm starting with sed.
Can anybody lead me to way how to solve this problem?
I start with this and I now basic commands of sed:

```
{0}{20}First subtitle
{30}{50}Second subtitle|New line is made this way.
{70}{100}Third.
{1010}{1033}Fourth etc.
```

The number in brackets mean start and end where the subtitle should be visible.
Let's have a translator who will make translations for the subtitles this way (
I'll sign this text (*)):

```
{0}{20}First subtitle
Translation of the first subtitle.
{30}{50}Second subtitle|New line is made this way.
Translation of the second subtitle.|Second line of translation of the second subtitle.
{70}{100}Third.
Translation of third.
{1010}{1033}Fourth etc.
Translation of fourth etc.
```

I need to do 3 things:
1) Separate the translated subtitles:

```
{0}{20}Translation of the first subtitle.
{30}{50}Translation of the second subtitle|Second line of translation of the second subtitle.
{70}{100}Translation of third.
{1010}{1033}Translation of fourth etc.
```

2) Separate from the text with both subtitles (signed with *) only original subtiltes and get this:

```
{0}{20}First subtitle
{30}{50}Second subtitle|New line is made this way.
{70}{100}Third.
{1010}{1033}Fourth etc.
```

3) Take the outputs from 1) and 2) and get the original text with both subtitles (signed *):

```
{0}{20}First subtitle
Translation of the first subtitle.
{30}{50}Second subtitle|New line is made this way.
Translation of the second subtitle.|Second line of translation of the second subtitle.
{70}{100}Third.
Translation of third.
{1010}{1033}Fourth etc.
Translation of fourth etc.
```

Can anybody please give me some advice how to start? Thanks a lot.

I should probably mention (which should be clear) that I'll call it like this:

```
cat input_file.txt | sed <"program" in sed>
```

Comment: [The homework tag has been deprecated and should no longer be used.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag)

Comment: What is "translation"? What have you tried? Also, you don't need to use `cat` with `sed`.

Comment: Translation is transforming text in one language to another language. 
Same as you just translate book for example from french to english, etc. In this context I have just original text in one language and translated text in other language. I tried another tasks in sed but I don't know where to start with this. I know that I don't need use the cat - It's just one way how to run it.

Comment: Is this for learning `sed`? You already have the end result (*), and you want to reconstruct it?

Comment: @doubleDown Yes. It's for learning sed.

Answer (score 0):

Once you save a translation of *subtitle file* `file_1` into *subtitle file* `file_2`, execute the command:

```
sed -r 's/^[{][0-9]+[}][{][0-9]+[}]//' file_2 | paste -d"\n" file_1 -
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it:

---

Steps 1 and 2: separate out the translated subtitle and original subtitle from (*) (I call it `sub_both` in the script below)

```
sed -r '
/^((\{[0-9]+\}){2}).*/ {
    w sub_orig
    s//\1/
    N
}
s/\n//
w sub_tran
' sub_both
```

What it does is:

1. Matches lines beginning with two sequence of digits enclosed in braces.
2. Write those lines to the file `sub_orig`
3. Replace the line with the 1st captured subexpression (which is the 2 sequences of digits)
4. Append next line (which is the translated line) to pattern space. As we recall, the pattern space after **3.** is just the 2 sequences of digit.
5. Remove the newline in pattern space, resulting in `{digits}{digits}translated line...`
6. Write the pattern space to file `sub_tran`

---

Step 3: Now that we have `sub_orig` and `sub_tran`, reconstruct (*) as `sub_both_2`

```
paste -d "\n" sub_orig <(sed -r '/^((\{[0-9]+\}){2})//' sub_tran) >sub_both_2
```

`sub_tran` is preprocessed via `sed` to remove the 2 sequences of digits, and the 2 files are merged with newline as the separator.

p/s: `<(command)` is process substitution which creates a temporary file from `command`.